# Extracting numbers from text file in powershell

Tags: powershell

I am trying to see if a variable exists in a text file using powershell.  select-string ends up retrieving all numbers with the number I am searching for.
c:\temp\numbers.txt has numbers in it like:
5
10
15
44

```
   $number = 5
   $test = get-content c:\temp\numbers.txt
   $test | select-string -pattern $number
```

This retrieves:
5
15

Is there a better way to do this?  How do I get just 5 to return?  Also bonus points on if there is a way to know which line 5 exists on.

Comment: the pattern you are using is regex ... so you need to specify _just the single digit `5`. right now, you are saying "match any 5 anywhere in the string".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`Select-String` can read the file so no need to use `Get-Content` in this example. `Select-String` returns an object that contains properties so you just need to pull the info you want out. Here is one way.

```
$file = 'c:\temp\numbers.txt'
$number = 5
Select-String -Path $file -Pattern $number | ForEach-Object {
    [PSCustomObject]@{
        Match = $_.matches.value
        Line  = $_.linenumber
    }
}
```

Outputs an object containing the value you matched and the line number it was on.

```
Match Line
----- ----
5        1
```

You can always capture output to a variable and inspect it with commands like `Get-Member` and `Format-List`

```
$variable = select-string -Path $file -pattern $number

$variable | Get-Member

TypeName: Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.MatchInfo

Name         MemberType Definition                                                       
----         ---------- ----------                                                       
Equals       Method     bool Equals(System.Object obj)                                   
GetHashCode  Method     int GetHashCode()                                                
GetType      Method     type GetType()                                                   
RelativePath Method     string RelativePath(string directory)                            
ToString     Method     string ToString(), string ToString(string directory)             
Context      Property   Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.MatchInfoContext Context {get;set;}
Filename     Property   string Filename {get;}                                           
IgnoreCase   Property   bool IgnoreCase {get;set;}                                       
Line         Property   string Line {get;set;}                                           
LineNumber   Property   int LineNumber {get;set;}                                        
Matches      Property   System.Text.RegularExpressions.Match[] Matches {get;set;}        
Path         Property   string Path {get;set;}                                           
Pattern      Property   string Pattern {get;set;}                                        


$variable | Format-List *

IgnoreCase : True
LineNumber : 1
Line       : 5 10 15 44
Filename   : numbers.txt
Path       : C:\temp\numbers.txt
Pattern    : 5
Context    : 
Matches    : {0}

$variable | Select-Object -ExpandProperty Matches | Format-List *

Groups   : {0}
Success  : True
Name     : 0
Captures : {0}
Index    : 0
Length   : 1
Value    : 5
```

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly, you want to match the number 5 as a whole word and want to have the line number returned aswell.

In that case surround the number you want to seek with regex 'Word Boundaries' (`\b`)

```
$number = 5
Select-String -Path 'C:\temp\numbers.txt' -Pattern "\b$number\b" | Select-Object Line, LineNumber | Format-List
```

to output something like

```
Line       : This line contains the number 5
LineNumber : 8

Line       : Usually, you have 5 fingers on each hand
LineNumber : 14
```